# Find the derivative of the function $ y= x|\cos{\frac{\pi}{x}}|$

Tags: derivatives

Function is defined as it follows : $x \neq 0$ and $f(0)=0$

My work is:

$\frac{d}{dx}(x|\cos{\frac{\pi}{x}}|)$ = $|\cos{\frac{\pi}{x}}|$ + $x(\frac{d}{dx}|\cos{\frac{\pi}{x}}|)$ = $|cos{\frac{\pi}{x}}|$ + $\frac{\pi}{x}(\operatorname{sgn}(\cos{\frac{\pi}{x}}))(\sin{\frac{\pi}{x}})$ = $\operatorname{sgn}(\cos{\frac{\pi}{x}})[(\cos{\frac{\pi}{x}}) + \frac{\pi}{x}(\sin{\frac{\pi}{x}})]$

Should I consider any points on the domain and find the derivative of the function on those points?

Thank you

Comment: The derivative at $x=0$ needs to be calculated separately.

Comment: @GoodDeeds i can't see the mistake in my calculation? Are there any other points to be mentioned?

Comment: But there is a $x$ multiplying that expression.

Comment: Yes you are right that was careless of me, sorry.

Comment: Just wondering as an alternative, would it be easier to write that absolute value term as the square root of its square and then taking a derivative?

Comment: You need to take care of $x_0=0$ and of  those points where $\cos  (\pi/x)=0$ separately, since the modulus is not differentiable at $0$.

Comment: $x=0$ is an essential singularity.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: The absolute value function $x \mapsto |x|$.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: Because everyone is doing this: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulus